# How to mock service in AngularJs to test Controller layer?

Tags: angularjs

I am working on AngularJs and want to write unit test for controller. Controller uses service and want to mock because on different response controller build different message for UI.
Not sure how to do that. Following is controller in which service is injected.
I am from java background and was thinking, if we have similar Mockito style testing. But could not find anything.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
// Controller
function SSODetailController($scope, $state, testService, $uibModal, $uibModalStack) {
    var vm = this;
    $scope.testExecution = function(id) {
        
        testService.testFuntion(id)
        .then(function(data) {
                vm.testUsers(id, data)
                return;
            
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                return err;
            });
    };
    
    vm.testUsers = function (id, data) {
        var testModal = document.getElementById("test-modal");
        var pTag = document.getElementById("test-message");
        var severityLevel =  data.failed > 0 ? 'ERROR: ' : 'INFO: ';
        pTag.innerHTML = severityLevel + data.test
        testModal.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

UNIT TEST

```
'use strict';
describe('test block', function() {
    beforeEach(module('test'));

    var $rootScope,
        compile,
        element,
        $state,
        $service,
        $controller,
        testService,
        htmlTemplate;

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _$rootScope_, _$state_, _$compile_, _$templateCache_, _testService) {
        htmlTemplate = _$templateCache_.get('app/components//test.html');
        compile = _$compile_;
        $state = _$state_;
        testService = _testService,
        $controller = _$controller_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        element = compile(htmlTemplate)($rootScope);
        $rootScope.$digest();
        
        spyOn(testService, 'testFuntion').and.callThrough();
    }
    
    
    it('Test message', function() {
        expect(element.find("#test-message").text()).toBe("success");
    });
    
    it('Test message', function() {
        expect(element.find("#test-message").text()).toBe("failed");
    });
    
}
```